# How to generate a random floating number in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have defined a function in python 3 which takes a floating point number as it's argument and rounds it up to 2 decimal places. So to test my program I want to generate 10 random floating point number between -1000 to 1000 and check for the output

I want my program to work in the following manner:

```py
    def precision(floating_num):
        floating_num *= 1000
        floating_num = int(floating_num)
        digit = floating_num % 10
        if digit >= 5:
            floating_num += 10 - digit
        else:
            floating_num -= digit
        floating_num = floating_num / 1000
        print('Output:',floating_num)
    
    for i in range(0,10,1):
        floating_num = '''random floating number in the range -1000 to 1000'''
        print('Input:',floating_num)
        precision(floating_num)
```

P.S. : I am editing my answer so that you guys can have a look at the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this can tell me if it fits your criteria:

```
import random
def precision(floating_num):
    floating_num = round(floating_num,2)
    return floating_num

for i in range(0,10,1):
    floating_num = random.uniform(-1000,1000)
    output = precision(floating_num)
    print('Input: ',floating_num)
    print('Output: ',output)
```

As you requested in the comments without round:

```
import random
def precision(floating_num):
    floating_num = str(floating_num)
    lindex = 0
    index = floating_num.index(".")+1
    floating_num = float(floating_num[0:index+2])
        
    return floating_num

for i in range(0,10,1):
    floating_num = random.uniform(-1000,1000)
    output = precision(floating_num)
    print('Input: ',floating_num)
    print('Output: ',output)
```

Comment: this one works perfect, btw my teacher specifically asked me not to use the round function but I think my code is kinda lengthy do you have any ideas how to trim it down a bit without using the round function?

Comment: Let me check on that one

Comment: Ok test it now.